# My cursor fetch throws null in every variable

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, xampp, fetch

So I have this procedure:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE noRow int(5);
DECLARE codmensc int(5);
DECLARE titulosc varchar(30);
DECLARE emisorsc varchar(30);
DECLARE nombmedsc varchar(30);
DECLARE cantsc int(5);
DECLARE codmedsc int(5);
DECLARE totsc double(8,2);
DECLARE calo CURSOR FOR
    SELECT m.codmen, m.titulo, m.emisor, me.nombmed, m.cant, m.codmed, m.cant*me.precunit as tot 
    FROM mensaje m 
    JOIN medicina me on m.codmed=me.codmed 
    JOIN cliente c on c.codcli = m.codcli 
    WHERE c.usuario = usuarioactual;
    
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET noRow = 0;

OPEN calo;

LOOPROWS: LOOP
        IF noRow = 0 THEN
            CLOSE calo;
            LEAVE LOOPROWS;
        END IF;
        
        FETCH calo INTO codmensc, titulosc, emisorsc, nombmedsc, cantsc, codmedsc, totsc;
        
        SELECT codmensc , titulosc , emisorsc , nombmedsc , cantsc , totsc;

    END LOOP;
END
```

It was created with no exceptions, but when I call it, it gives me this result:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijNdW.png)

At first, my variables where named like the select attributes in the cursor. I changed them, expecting for that to be the problem, but it kept throwing null.

P.S: Every table has data.

Comment: You don't need local variables, or a cursor, or a loop for this. Just run the SELECT query. One statement.

Comment: Thank you for clearing my mind, I think I used a procedure because I wanted to use if statements. (Just remembered you can call ifs in the SELECT query)